# Constructing sequence whose subsequence converges to given point always exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to construct a sequence in R^2 such that for any x in R^2, there exist a subsequence converging to x ?

Comment: Enumerate rationals?

Comment: That's what I thought at first but how to write it as a sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb Q^2$ is dense in $\newcommand{\epi}{\twoheadrightarrow}\mathbb R^2$, so all we need is a surjection $\mathbb N\epi \mathbb Q^2.$ It might be tricky to write it directly, so I'll just break it into simpler problems:

$$\mathbb N\to\mathbb N^2\to \mathbb N^4 \to \mathbb Z\times\mathbb N\times \mathbb Z\times\mathbb N \to \mathbb Q^2.$$

I leave it to you as an exercise to fill the arrows. One more hint: you need bijections $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N^2$ and $\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by this Z×N×Z×N→Q2, what dose the notation mean? An integer multiply with a natural number multiply with an integer and multiply with a natural number is rational number? Why?

Comment: @Edwards, its the map $(a,b,c,d)\mapsto (a/b,c/d)$. That's how we define rationals (up to equivalence classes).